# Title suddenly becomes required field for old libraries

Tags: document-library, content-type, document

I have one site collection (SharePoint 2013 Foundation) which includes many sites and lists/libraries under it.

My end users are now complaining that, since a few days ago, they are getting the **Title** field as a required field after uploading document. They have not used this field before in the libraries they are using.

I don't think I have installed or activated any new feature, nor have I installed any patches.

Comment: Did anyone edit Site Content Types recently?  I've made the mistake of changing a Site Content Type too high up in the hierarchy and it reset the Title field to it's default settings of being called "Title" and making it required.  In our case, we were using the Title field but renamed it in many places, so take a look at that, even though they say they have not used the field before; it could have been called something else.

Answer (score 2):

Did anyone edit Site Content Types recently? I've made the mistake of changing a Site Content Type too high up in the hierarchy and it reset the Title field to its default settings of being called "Title" and making it required.

In our case, we were using the Title field but renamed it in many places at the list/library level, so take a look at that.  Even though they say they have not used the field before, it could have been renamed to something else.

Read more about Content Types in SharePoint 2013 [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262735.aspx).